# stream with nodejs (io.js), backpressure and drain, `end` event is called twice

Tags: node.js, io.js

I have this code. The `end` event is fired two times. I can't understand why. Any hints? Thanks.

```
var chance = require('chance').Chance();

require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  function generateMore() {
    while(chance.bool({likelihood: 95})) {
      var shouldContinue = res.write(
        chance.string({length: (16 * 1024) - 1})
      );
      if(!shouldContinue) {
        console.log('Backpressure');
        return res.once('drain', generateMore);
      }
    }
    res.end('\nThe end...\n', function() {
      console.log('All data was sent'); // I see this log two times
    });
  }

  generateMore();

}).listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Listening');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Because when you open URL, browser tries get favicon.ico and sends two requests to your server.

Comment: so simple, so true. Thanks.

Comment: I know that feel with second request=)